# How can I start a shell inside a jail on FreeBSD?

Tags: unix, shell, freebsd, jail

I have access to a a previously set up FreeBSD box with a number of jails on it. One of the jails is an SQL server, and does not have ssh enabled on it.

How can I gain access to a shell on that jail from the host machine? (I have root rights on it.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First run `jls` to find out needed jail ID, then `jexec ${jailID} /bin/tcsh` (${jailID} is an ID of your jail)

Comment: +1 You might add that jails don't have shells (though you can start one in the same jail as another application), they aren't OS virtualization, they are application/userland virtualization. The jails all share the same kernel. [More in the handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html).

Comment: Even more, jail is essentially just resource isolation, not virtualization. There is another project more close to virtualization: http://www.7he.at/freebsd/vps/